# Contained 3D Window in PyQt5

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyqt5, qt3d

I'm using PyQt5 and trying to implement a contained 3D window into a python file generated from a .ui file. I made a contained3dWindow class which inherits from QWidget that just creates a 3D window, and I am trying to add the contained window to a VBoxLayout in the main window file. But, when I create an instance of my contained3dWindow class in my main window file, I get this error message:

> Warning: Setting a new default format with a different version or profile after the global shared context is created may cause issues with context sharing.
>   Failed to make context current: OpenGL resources will not be destroyed

When I run the main file, the main window displays for less than a second, and the program closes. This is the function for the contained window, which is in the file cwindow.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QCommandLinkButton, \
    QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.Qt3DExtras import QTorusMesh, QPhongMaterial, QConeMesh, QCylinderMesh, \
    QCuboidMesh, QPlaneMesh, QSphereMesh, Qt3DWindow, QFirstPersonCameraController

import sys

class contained3dWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        view = Qt3DWindow()
```

This is the code in the main window file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cwindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #Generated by pyuic
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1416, 1041)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 160, 1051, 721))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1416, 38))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        #Source of the problem. Error occurs when the contained3dWindow instance is created
        c_window = cwindow.contained3dWindow()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(c_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A contained3dWindow object is created in the setupUi function, and the program runs as expected if the object is not created. The PyQt documentation is very slim, and I only found one other person who had this issue (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60614). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know exactly what is the cause of the error, I suspect it has to do with the release of memory but the following code does not generate that problem, so for now I should solve your problem

**cwindow.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.Qt3DExtras import Qt3DWindow, QFirstPersonCameraController
from PyQt5.Qt3DCore import QEntity

class contained3dWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view = Qt3DWindow()
        container = QWidget.createWindowContainer(self.view)
        lay.addWidget(container)
        self.rootEntity = QEntity()
        cameraEntity = self.view.camera()
        camController = QFirstPersonCameraController(self.rootEntity)
        camController.setCamera(cameraEntity)
        self.view.setRootEntity(self.rootEntity)
```

Comment: I am getting this error -  No module named 'PyQt5.Qt3DExtras'

Comment: @DanielHenneh Do you have PyQt3D installed? https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt3d/download

Comment: I just did, and everything is fine now. Thanks!